# Amazon Checkout Equivalent for Google Checkout Server to Server Communication

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, google-checkout, amazon-fps

Googlecheckout allows you to CURL the customers order, they return a URL and then you send the user to the URL, so they can not see the data you sent good and thus they can not modify it.

I see there is polling requests for Amazon Checkout with CURL, but is it does the same function exist in Amazon Checkout, or Amazon FPS (flexible Payment system)?

Google Code: https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API#api_details
https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API#integration_overview // CURL Example, scroll a down little bit from here.

```
_type=checkout-shopping-cart
&shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-name=Peanut%20Butter
&shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-name=Strawberry%20Jelly
&shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-description=Made%20from%20peanuts
&shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-description=Made%20from%20strawberries
```

Thus the request would look like this.

```
curl -d '_type=checkout-shopping-cart&shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-name=Peanut%20Butter&shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-name=Strawberry%20Jelly&shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-description=Made%20from%20peanuts&shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-description=Made%20from%20strawberries'
https://P_MERCHANT_ID:P_MERCHANT_KEY@checkout.google.com/api/checkout/v2/requestForm/Merchant/P_MERCHANT_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly amazon is lacking in documentation or it is at least hard to find.  You might try asking them at https://aws.amazon.com/support/